# Don't understand why code goes into infinite loop

Tags: java

I am trying to learn Java and I have been having a hard time using the `Scanner` class. What I want to do is to accept an integer using `Scanner.nextInt()` method. Along with this, I want to check if the input is a number or not. If not, I want to ask the user to enter the input again.

Here is the code which I wrote to accomplish this :

```
  do
  {
   System.out.print("Please enter Side 1:\t");

   if(scanner.hasNextInt())
   {
     d1=(double)scanner.nextInt();
     i=0;
   }
   else
   {
     System.out.print("Side shoud be a number!\t");
     i=1;
   }

  }
  while(i!=0);
```

This unfortunately goes into a infinite loop, what I understand is that it doesn't wait for the 'return' in the second loop.

Comment: While it is in its "infinite loop", what happens if you type a number and press enter?

Comment: Print out the content of the Scanner to see what's actually happening.

Comment: All it takes is for hasNextInt to be false.

Comment: If you step through the code in a debugger you will be able to work it out for yourself.  Note: `scanner.hashNextInt()` will keep returning false in your case once it starts.  There is nothing to reset it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some people seem to think it's a simple mistake of swapping the 1 or 0, or the condition should be flipped - but this isn't the case. If you made this change, then you would just get continual prompting for numbers even though you already got one.

You want to only continue prompting if the input was not an integer, and stop prompting the moment you get that integer, right?

I would recommend using a try-catch and a form of the Parse method so it is clear what you would like to do.

(Also, your integer i doesn't need to be an integer - it could just be a boolean (true or false). This also would make the intent of the variable clearer. Naming your variables well is important for good code.)

See this:

```
import java.io.*;                                                                   
import java.util.*;                                                                 

class Test {                                                                        
  public static void main(String args[]) {                                          
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);                                       
    boolean done = false;                                                           
    double d1 = 0;                                                                  
    do {                                                                            
      System.out.print("Please enter Side 1:\t");                                   
      String next = scanner.next();                                                 
      try {                                                                         
        d1 = Double.parseDouble(next);                                              
        done = true;                                                                
      } catch (Exception e) {                                                       
        System.out.print("Side should be a number!\t");                              
      }                                                                             
    }                                                                               
    while(!done);   
    System.out.println("Number obtained: " + d1);                                                                
  }                                                                                 
}
```

This only continues prompting if you didn't get a double. Once you get a double, it stops.

Comment: Also, in your problem-statement you say you want to read an integer, but you're storing it in a double, so I have it here so that you are trying to read doubles. This could easily be changed to Integer.parseInt(someStringThatCouldBeAnInteger) to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You do not consume the incorrect input in the else branch, so if `scanner.hasNextInt()` returns `false` you will enter an infinite loop, because at the next iteration the same scanner state is seen.

Comment: Yeah I know why it goes in the infinite loop as the if condition has the same input in every loop,the problem according to me is that scanner doesn;t wait for a 'return'  i.e user to enter side in the second loop and so on

Comment: throw in a `scanner.nextLine()` at an appropriate place.

Comment: I got it I intialize the scanner object inside the loop,now it working good, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If `scanner.hasNextInt()` returns true then it should work but when it returns false it will enter infinite loop.

How about this:-

```
do
  {
   System.out.print("Please enter Side 1:\t");


  if(scanner.hasNextInt())
  {
   d1=(double)scanner.nextInt();
   i=0;

  }
   else
   {
   System.out.print("Side shoud be a number!\t");
   i=1;
   scanner.nextLine();
   }

  }
  while(i!=0);
```

or try to change your while loop like  this:-

```
 while(i==0);
```

Comment: then it won't accomplish what I want ,i want it go in the loop when the input is not number so the new input can be a number

Comment: Then probably you need to have scanner.nextLine();

Answer (score 0):

You get stuck in the infinite loop becuase there isn't any method call for the scanner next line. See the bold line addition.

```
    do {
        System.out.print("Please enter Side 1:\t");

        if(scanner.hasNextInt()) {  
            double d1=(double)scanner.nextInt();
            i=0;
        }

        else {
            System.out.print("Side shoud be a number!\t");
            i=1;
        }

        **scanner.nextLine();**
           }
    while(i!=0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Guys I finally got it all I needed to do was to initialize the scanner object inside the loop so it wait every time the loop execute heres the code:

```
do
  {
   System.out.print("Please enter Side 1:\t");
  scanner=new Scanner(System.in);

  if(scanner.hasNextInt())
  {
   d1=(double)scanner.nextInt();
   i=0;

  }
   else
   {
   System.out.print("Side shoud be a number!\t");
   i=1;
   }

  }
  while(i==1);
```

Thanks for responses tho.

Comment: This isn't necessarily good code though - you may want to see the alternate solution I wrote above.

Comment: Yes I tried the try catch method before I tried the hasInt method but when I used the try catch it showed a system message in scanner class into tho I had a a simple message in the catch loop ,would try ur code and see if it gives the same